# Maven "clean install site" fails for JPA Metamodel generated classes

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am working on a JPA/Hibernate application which generates the JPA Metamodels using maven-processor-plugin

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>process</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
           </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                  <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
             </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     </plugin>
```

When I try to execute **mvn clean install site** it fails with the following error on Metamodel classes"

```
  error: Person_ is already defined as object Person_
```

But when I execute **mvn clean install** and then **mvn site**, it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated with this. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share output of `mvn clean install site -X` and the whole `pom.xml` file of yours.

Comment: Here is my pom.xml - http://pastebin.com/vu1gvmSQ

Comment: And also a debug output will be great mvn clean install site -X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. It required the following plugin to work.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I also added the below configuration to the **maven-processor-plugin** I am using.

```
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
```